# how to print a page using asp:button in c#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I want print the current page when click on asp:button. How can to achieve that?

I have google this thing for help but every time I end up finding it for windows application and I am working on web application in .net.

Is there any **command** or any **jquery** which can help me to do that?

Please suggest something!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try window.print() (javascript):
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_print.asp